# How can I repeat a method with a variable integer?

Tags: java

I just started learning how to program in Java a month ago. I am trying to make my robot (karel) put a beeper the amount of times that is indicated in the "put" integer only, not the total amount the object has. However, it is not a set number and `karel.putBeeper(put);` does not get accepted in the compiler due to the class not being applied to given types. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am starting to understand why Stack Overflow is a programmer's best friend lol. Note: I might not respond to to any helpful tips until tomorrow.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Lab09 {
   public static void main(String[]args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Which world?");
      String filename = input.nextLine();
      World.readWorld(filename);
      World.setSize(10,10);
      World.setSpeed(6);
      Robot karel = new Robot(1,1,World.EAST,0);
      int pick=0;
      int put=0;
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
         while(karel.onABeeper()) {
            karel.pickBeeper();
            pick++;
            karel.move();
         }
         for(i=0; pick>i; pick--) {
            put++;
         }
         if(!karel.onABeeper()) {
            karel.move();
         }
         while(karel.onABeeper() && put>0) {
            karel.putBeeper(put);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, you're trying to `putBeeper` `put` times, which is done by the following code:

```
while (karel.onABeeper() && put > 0) {
  karel.putBeeper(put);
}
```

The issue I see here is that you're not changing the value of `put` after calls to `putBeeper`, hence this `while` loop will never terminate: for instance, if the value of `put` was `5` during the first loop iteration, it will always remain `5`, which is larger than `0`. Also, as you've mentioned, `putBeeper` doesn't take any arguments, hence trying to pass `put` as an argument won't work - the compiler catches that error for you.

If your intent is to call `putBeeper` `put` times then what you can do is decrement `put` after every invocation of `putBeeper` - `put` will eventually reach `0`, at which point you've called `putBeeper` exactly `put` times. And since you're just learn to program in Java, I'll leave the actual implementation to you as an exercise. Good luck!